# Myriad Pro font issue in Adobe products

Tags: fonts, adobe

I have hit upon a unique problem and wanted to know if others see it and if they have any thoughts on it.  I had a friend reproduce this.

1. Open Photoshop or Illustrator (I am using CS5/Win7) to a new
   document
2. Using the text tool type the word Office and change the
   font to Myriad Pro
3. The dot over the i goes missing.
4. Now it gets weirder.  In either, select the text and set the tracking to a
   crazy high number (200 or so)
5. For me the word tracks out EXCEPT FOR THE "ffi" which does not change.

Anyone else seeing this and do you know if there is a fix for this?  The only thing I know to do is open up a new text layer and overlay the i over a space I leave in"off ce"

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Not sure how this qualifies as a programming-related question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, OpenType standard ligatures are enabled in Photoshop documents. You can easily change this behavior by opening the Character Palette, using the small drop-down menu on the right, and unchecking "Standard Ligatures" under "OpenType".

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not know about ligatures and therefore didn't know what to search for.  Once you pointed out the place to untick it, they went away.  Thanks for that info.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the behavior you want but this sounds like it's by design. That's a ligature. It's suppose to be nicer looking to combine f when followed by i to an 'fi' ligature. Same for ffi.

Comment: He's right, though. It really does look awful when you crank the tracking up. It would be more sensible to have a tracking threshold above which ligatures are broken apart into their component glyphs.